# Glassfish: Storing Java classes in the docroot folder?

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish

I'm very new to using Glassfish or JSP.

I have this working in NetBeans (which has Glassfish bundled) but when I try to put it on my server which is running Glassfish Server, I really don't know what I'm doing.

I can place a JSP file in "domains/domain1/docroot/index.jsp" and it will work when I visit my site, but I can't, for some reason, get Java classes to work.

I copied the files in "/build/web/" from the NetBeans project to the docroot folder on my server.

The errors I get when I visit the site are:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
string:///index_jsp.java:7: package test does not exist

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
string:///index_jsp.java:52: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TestClass
location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
string:///index_jsp.java:52: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TestClass
location: class org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
```

The actual Java class is in "WEB-INF/classes/test/TestClass.class" (it is pre-compiled).

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*'Cause you're doing it wrong* - you need to make a web archive first (war). You should probably start with this, really:

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html

And for a quick start refer to figure 3-5 here:

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html

Comment: I am new so can't vote up. 
Yes I agree with Michał Minicki. The standard and simplest way is to create war file to deploy your web application.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use the docroot folder. That might work for static contents like html, but even that is not a good idea.

The simplest way is to create a new folder called myapp.war and copy your target folder (from netbeans to this folder.Obviously I am over simplifying and but I am trying to get my point across )

Also you should be able to create a web app in  netbeans deploy in place to glassfish.